# I have a few EMF files. How I can convert them into ps/pdf/tiff on Linux?

Tags: linux, graphic

I have few EMF (Enhanced Windows Metafile) files. How I can convert them into ps/pdf/tiff on Linux (CentOS 5.x)? Command line interface is preferred.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) can convert emf to pdf and tiff via command-line:
For pdf: unoconv filename.emf
For tiff: unoconv -f tiff filename.emf
It doesn't seem to support ps file export, though.
You are still required to install OpenOffice.org/LibreOffice because this tool uses them as the backend.

Answer (score 1):

as far I know, to convert **EMF** to **.ps** and **.pdf**, keeping vector quality, you need to import in OpenOffice and then generate a **pdf** that you can convert in a ps with **pdftops**

a command-line tool (as import filter for **sk1**), is in preparation, but it seems not yet ready:

- http://sk1project.org/modules.php?name=Products&product=pymfvu

you can then, once made a pdf, convert from pdf format to tiff with latest releases of **pdftoppm** (despite its name it has gained ability to convert to tiff format) or use **pdftocairo** at desired resolution

- http://poppler.freedesktop.org/releases.html